# Linear Regression Function for Sin Graph

Tags: regression, linear-regression, trigonometry, period

I am currently working on a project where I must analyze data and find a period for the graph. The data contains outliers. I need a function that will make a line of best fit for the function.

I attempted to simply get a sin graph on the plot, but I could not even do that. Can anyone give me a starting hint?

```
import os
import pyfits as fits
import numpy as np
import pylab
import random
import scipy.optimize
import scipy.signal

from numpy import arange
from matplotlib import pyplot
from scipy.optimize import curve_fit

filename = 'C:\Users\Ken Preiser\Desktop\Space thing\Snapshots\BAT_70m_snapshot_SWIFT_J1647.9-4511B.lc'
namePortion = filename[-39:]

hdulist = fits.open(filename, 'readonly', None, False) #{unpacks file) name, mode, memorymap, savebackup
data = hdulist[1].data

datapoints = 23310

def sinfunc(a, b, c): #I tried graphing a sinfunction, but it did not work...
    return a*np.sin(bx-c) 

time = data.field('TIME')
time = time / 86400.0

timeViewingThreshold = 10
rateViewingThreshold = .01

rate = np.sum(data['RATE'][:,:4], axis=1)

average = np.sum(rate)/23310

error = data.field('ERROR')
error = np.sqrt(np.sum(data['ERROR'][:,:4]**2, axis=1))

print rate.size,(", rate")
print time.size,(", time")

fig = pylab.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(111)

ax.set_xlabel('Time')
ax.set_ylabel('Rate')
ax.set_title('Rate vs Time graph: ' + namePortion)

pylab.plot(time, rate, 'o')
pyplot.xlim(min(time) - timeViewingThreshold, max(time) + timeViewingThreshold)
pyplot.ylim(min(rate) - rateViewingThreshold, max(rate) + rateViewingThreshold)
ax.errorbar(time, rate, xerr=0, yerr=error)
pylab.show()
```

(the outputs)
https://i.stack.imgur.com/WYGgj.jpg

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to fit points to the model: y = sin(ax + b).  Since you're using linear regression, you need a linear model.  So one way to do that is compute arcsin for each point and now compute the linear regression.  The model is now: arcsin(y) = ax + b.  The regression model gives you a and b which is what you're after.  You should be able to test this out pretty quickly in excel, then code it up once the nuances are figured out.